# onCheckedChanged viewpager fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In viewpager's fragment; I've a checkbox with OnCheckedChangeListener.

Fragment's current index position is shown in page correctly. BUT when I click checkbox (`onCheckedChanged`):

- It shows next position number

How can I use `onCheckedChanged` with current position ?

```
    public class PageFragment extends Fragment {  

     private static int currentQuestionNumber;
     private static CheckBox review;
         public static PageFragment newInstance(int index ) {

             PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
             bundle.putInt("index", index);
             pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
             return pageFragment;
         }


    @Override  
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     PageFragment.currentQuestionNumber = getArguments().getInt("index");
    review = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.Review); 

    PageFragment.review.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

             @Override 
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), PageFragment.currentQuestionNumber  // shows next index number
+"-" +isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     

             }

         });        
    }
    }
```

Comment: your PageFragment Fragment is in which position in your viewpager.when your clicking in what postion its showing.

Comment: it is auto updating content; just one fragment when switch pages it loads positions; but  onCheckedChanged shows next page position

Comment: but i have tested your code its showing zero always.can you please post your code where your adding fragments to your viewpager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index refers to next page because viewpager will preload the next fragment when displaying the current item. Try use yourViewPager.getCurrentItem() to get the index of the displaying position.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting position from PageFragment newInstance. Now I set value with getCurrentItem() and worked.